# how to search an element in c++ containers using a class

Tags: c++

I have a code which uses a class and its members to find elements inside a container e.g., vectors as given below. I am using find function to get an element but see an error "C2678 binary '==:' no operator found which takes a left hand operand of type 'file_element'.. "

```
class file_element
{
public:
    int line_no;
    std::string line;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::vector<file_element> elements
    {
        {1, "This"},
        {1, "is"},
        {1, "Arif"},
        {1, "."},
        {2, "I"},
        {2, "work"}
    };

    std::vector<file_element>::iterator it = find(elements.begin(), elements.end(), '.');
    if ( it != elements.end())
        std::cout << "element: " << (*it).line << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "element not found " << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Error I see seems to be at line where if condition is defined. Code I have written the same way as most of examples of internet are showing. What is wrong and what can be a solution to this problem?

Comment: You need a lambda expression to check if a `file_element` `line` member contains a `'.'`, use that one with `std::find_if()` then.

Comment: @TheDude I am trying to learn function find on these examples. Books and internet tell a specific way which I have applied above, but that works only probably in the examples of books.

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect `find` to get the element you want when you give it `'.'`? The compiler cannot read your mind.

`find` will try to use `operator== (file_element, char)` to find your element but there is no such operator defined.

You can either define an operator or supply a function and use `find_if` like so:

```
std::vector<file_element>::iterator it = std::find_if(elements.begin(), elements.end(), 
  [](const file_element& element) {
    return element.line == "."; // or something
  });
```

Comment: I used your code lines instead of std::vector<file_element>::iterator it = find(elements.begin(), elements.end(), '.'); but error remains same. can you explain your point a bit more?

Comment: oh dear, I made a critical error... you need `find_if` to use a predicate not `find`, edited